# Progressive disclosure on hover - Best approach?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, interface, component, progressive-disclosure

## **Context:**

I'm the sole product designer for a company with a product built around selling "knowledge packages" for getting your company on a better spot financially, fiscally, or productively.

I'm building the content builder for our employees to then publish to users, and the solution we ended up going for after doing research and establishing our value proposition was a "modular document builder" which we can build other features on top of in the future aligning with our product strategy.

I know I'm being vague, but I wouldn't want to reveal too much. Let me know if you need more info!

## **The problem:**

This content builder has Sections, which contain Rows; Rows contain components, which act as columns; Components can be Cards, Text, tables, etc.

These components can be dragged around the screen into different rows and/or sections through Drag'n'Drop indicator on the top left corner, and on the top right there is an option for additional actions. (Drag'n'Drop + Additional Actions = Action Bar)

When I came into the company, they had the Action Bar set to "always visible" on all components around the screen, but it made the screen crowded and added too much noise, and did not allow users to read the screen easily. I'm introducing Progressive Disclosure but I'm finding myself in a bit of a pickle which I'm having trouble fixing.

> **The issue is that this "Action Bar" appears on hover, but I don't** **know how to find an appropriate way to make it appear.**

## **What I've explored:**

- Resize and move. The action bar appears on hover instantly and makes the content box longer and displaces the content below. It is the option that I'm most inclined toward, but I still don't feel it is the right one as it might break the layout and displace the content.
- Cover. This simply doesn't work except for images. It goes over the content and can difficult editing the text on the top row.

There is also the option to reserve the space on top and add the same amount of padding on the bottom, which I'm not really fond of as it might add unjustified white space which can affect how users scan the content and break items related through the law of proximity. Here's a simple wireframe to support what I'm talking about.

[image]

Am I taking the right approach? Do you have any suggestions? Have you already solved this before?

Thanks so much, guys!

Comment: How is this action bar triggered for people who aren't using a mouse?

Comment: Have you explored using a simple three-dot menu that appears over the card on hover for editing options, and just making the section/card draggable without an icon to click? If the user clicks and holds, the card becomes draggable.

Comment: @JonW Hi Jon, are you referencing this for accessibility reasons? The product is not mature enough at the moment and it doesn't have as many users to take into account people who do not use their mouse. As in, dev and design resources are invested in things that bring intrinsic value. We are still in the "angel investors" phase. 

Could you provide more backing on not considering this an edge case? Could we get fined over this? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Izquierdo Thank you so much for your answer. Yes, that should definitely be an option. I'm taking into account also our current state of this interaction and trying to add value to it without loading our limited dev resources. 

Another worry is I might be losing visual feedback on "Dragability". What do you think?

Also, wouldn't this still show the three doted menu _over_ it? Or did you have something else in mind?

Again, thanks for your time and looking forward to read your answer!

Comment: Do you have a Google homepage in Chrome? They to do a good job with showing the dot menu on hover, and making the tile look interactive (dragable).

Comment: @Izquierdo Been playing around and I don't know if I know what you mean. Do you have a link to it/to a video/or a few pictures? Cheers!

Comment: If you're concerned about the toolbar menu covering or displacing the content, then why not float it next to the card?

Comment: It's a classic mistake to think accessibility can be thought of later. You are in the position to get it right from the start, something that many designers and developers will envy who are now struggling to make their existing product accessible.

Comment: @jazZRo Thank you for your feedback. I truly appreciate it. And even though I completely agree with your statement and I've taken the necessary steps to have the basics right, resources are something I have to juggle with to make prioritization decisions. At the moment, with me as the sole designer and our app lacking in some central areas to our core value as the company didn't have a full-time designer for a bit, I feel some other things stand higher on the list of "to-do's". However, I'll keep it in mind for our next efforts when these core issues are fixed. Again, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The whole list is going into an edit mode. So you could put an edit button at the top of the list that enables an edit mode where all the "action bars" are showing

Here's an example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey moot! Thanks for your commentt. Yes, that is exactly the approach we followed at the start, and I even added a color group exclusively for edit mode as feedback that the user was editing (As we got feedback that users didnt know if they were editing or not) However, this approach made the screen look super crowded and users had issues reading it. I'll try to explore this approach to see if there is a way of making it less crowded by changing colors.

Comment: Ah, you tried this? You only said you tried with the bars always showing. Was the top list title and buttons frozen or part of the list? Users would hit the EDIT LIST button and not know what happened? Or would they move on and forget they hit it?

Comment: Yes, by the bar I meant the top card menu with the drag and drop indicator and the more options button. 

Actually, it was more subtle than that. Showing the bars provided nice feedback that you were now editing the list. However, users took more time to find the components they wanted to edit given a specific task (and even knowing where the object is) because the screen was crowded with interactable bars. We chose to have the bar only be shown upon hover, and that fixed it.

However, the content was being pushed down, which broke the layout and confused users.

Answer (score 0):

The control bar can extend upward, and over what is above, therefore not affecting layout. It hides some content, but not on the card being manipulated.

[image: cards]
[image: cards controls]

---

See it in action:

[image: cards animated]